# Display posts from current category in archives

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking, if is possible, for a way to display posts from a certain category. Less say I'm reading a post and in footer or sidebar I have the "Archives" widget but what I want is to display, when I click for example "September 2013", posts from this month but also the same category where previous posts belongs to, any advice?

**UPDATE**
I'll try to explain a bit more what I want to do. Suppose I'm visiting this link:

```
`http://localwordpress/category/some-text-from-entry`
```

This is a post page, and in footer I have the archive widget, more or less:

```
October 2013
September 2013
August 2013
....
```

**NOTE:** This is in case I change permalinks to `/%category%/%postname%/`. By default if you click on any link in archive widget meaning `October 2013`, `September 2013` ... you'll get all entries from the month but in adition I need to filter those entries by `category` where category will be get from URL for the post I'm seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your links like this :

```
http://yoururl.com/2013/9/?category_name=new
```

where new is the category name that you want or like this

```
http://yoururl.com/2013/9/?cat=1
```

where the number 1 is the category id that you want

You have to open the php file that render this links and modify accordingly. ie

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '/?category_name=' . get_cat_name( $cat_id ) . '"></a>';
```

or

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '/?cat=' . $cat_id . '"></a>';
```

## UPDATE

More about query variables here :

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars

Comment: I'll take a look but, if I change my permalinks to `/%category%/%postname%/` how I can get the category_name? By using [Query Post Category Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Category_Parameters)? Any example besides the one you leave me?

Comment: I din't mean to change the permalinks. Would you mind to explain me better what you mean or want you want to do. Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at the main post, I edited adding more info

Comment: Thanks. What is the link that the widget produces for a month ie for October ?

Comment: Something like `http://localwordpress/blog/2013/09/` (I'm using localwordpress as a wilcard)

Comment: The archive structure /year/month/ will not change if you change your permalink structure. It only change when you set your permalinks to default (something like this : http://localwordpress/?p=124 ).But if you want to do it no matter the link structure you can do it like this : http://localwordpress/?m201310&cat=1

Comment: Still not understanding how to achieve this, now I'm complete lost

Comment: Try to write in the url bar of chrome something like that http://locawordpress/?m=201310&category_name=new. Is it working ? Try to play a bit by changing the date and the category and see how is going ? If is working that is the links that you should output into the footer. I tried locally and it works. Sorry if I am not helpful. Can't think anything else to help you.