# Modifying Archive Widget in Wordpress so that it shows only posts from current category

Tags: wordpress, widget, posts

I was not able to find the exact solution here, so I'm posting a question.

So, I need a code that will turn Archive widget on every page to show only the pages/posts that are inside of the category on which you pressed it. for example if category is named "Acts" (url https://website.com/category/acts/) when you on the right sidebar press Archive and select month fromthe dropdown it will go to the url
https://website.com/2022/08/?category_name=acts instead of the usual https://website.com/2022/08/.

I would like to ask for a code I could put into my functions.php of the child theme so that it'd work. Also if possible to put the code so that it registers the modified archive widget as a new widget.

Thanks.

I tried several solutions here, but none of the worked. like:
[Display posts from current category in archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525592/display-posts-from-current-category-in-archives)
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176573/display-only-posts-from-referred-category-on-date-archive-page

I was able to identify that I actually just need the widget to work so that it forwards to the new URL mentioned above (the two posts above were helpful, but I wasn't able to get a complete answer)

Comment: If you are familiar with WordPress coding and core functions, then first of all you need to check if the current page is a taxonomy archive page which you can do using [is_tax](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) then you can use [get_queried_object()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) or [get_queried_object_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) to get the current taxonomy term object/ID, now you have the data to be used in your query or conditions for the logic build.

Comment: Hi Vijay, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, I'm not that much familiar with WP coding, and that is why I'm posted a question here, to learn something new. Could you care to write an example code for me to digest?